# Delete data from BigQuery while streaming from Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to delete data from a BigQuery table while loading data into it from an Apache Beam pipeline.

Our use case is such that we need to delete 3 days prior data from the table on the basis of a timestamp field (time when Dataflow pulls message from Pubsub topic).

Is it recommended to do something like this? If yes, is there any way to achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I think best way of doing this setup you table as partitioned (based on ingestion time) table https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables
And you can drop old partition manually

```
bq rm 'mydataset.mytable$20160301'
```

You can also set expiration time

```
bq update --time_partitioning_expiration [INTEGER] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]
```

If ingestion time does not work for you you can look into https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions - but it is in beta - works reliably but it is your call